# How can I get the data out of a table using Semantic UI React Table and Checkbox

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to implement a semantic ui table in react and include a column of checkboxes to select items from a row. I want to implement it to where the user can select all checkboxes by clicking the first checkbox or one item at a time and then print those values out but I'm struggling to be able to do that. Does anyone have any working examples of this by chance?